# ImGui-SFML cmake error when using git submodules

Tags: cmake, sfml, imgui

i'm doing a cmake for a project using sfml and imgui
I'm using submodules to get SFML, imgui and imgui-sfml from github and I have some errors and I can't find the cause.

my project structure is like this :

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
├── include
├── libs
│   ├── SFML
│   ├── imgui
│   └── imgui-sfml
├── src
└── tests
```

and my cmake is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(app)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(TEST_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests")
set(LIBS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs")
set(SFML_DIR "${LIBS_DIR}/SFML")
set(IMGUI_DIR "${LIBS_DIR}/imgui")
set(IMGUI_SFML_DIR "${LIBS_DIR}/imgui-sfml")

file(GLOB_RECURSE COMMON_SOURCES "${SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp" "${TEST_DIR}/*.cpp")
list(REMOVE_ITEM COMMON_SOURCES "${SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp" "${TEST_DIR}/main.cpp")

file(GLOB_RECURSE SFML_HEADERS "${SFML_DIR}/include/\*.hpp")

add_subdirectory(${LIBS_DIR}/sfml)

set(IMGUI_SFML_FIND_SFML OFF)
set(IMGUI_SFML_IMGUI_DEMO ON)
add_subdirectory(${IMGUI_SFML_DIR})

macro(create_target target sources)
add_executable(${target} ${sources})
target_sources(${target} PRIVATE ${COMMON_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${target} PRIVATE sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics ImGui-SFML::ImGui-SFML)
target_include_directories(${target} PRIVATE ${LIBS_DIR} ${INCLUDE_DIR} ${SFML_DIR}/include ${IMGUI_DIR} ${IMGUI_SFML_DIR})
endmacro()

create_target(app ${SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
create_target(test ${TEST_DIR}/main.cpp)
```

I have a lot of errors saying that the imgui-sfml can't find some sfml enums etc.. here is a sample of thoses:

```
 10%] Built target sfml-system
[ 45%] Built target sfml-window
[ 68%] Built target sfml-graphics
[ 68%] Building CXX object libs/imgui-sfml/CMakeFiles/ImGui-SFML.dir/imgui-SFML.cpp.o
/Users/loicpottier/Documents/GitHub/projet_recherche/libs/imgui-sfml/imgui-SFML.cpp:172:31: error: no member named 'X' in namespace 'sf::Joystick'
        xAxis = sf::Joystick::X;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/loicpottier/Documents/GitHub/projet_recherche/libs/imgui-sfml/imgui-SFML.cpp:173:31: error: no member named 'Y' in namespace 'sf::Joystick'
        yAxis = sf::Joystick::Y;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/loicpottier/Documents/GitHub/projet_recherche/libs/imgui-sfml/imgui-SFML.cpp:185:30: error: no member named 'Z' in namespace 'sf::Joystick'
        axis = sf::Joystick::Z;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/loicpottier/Documents/GitHub/projet_recherche/libs/imgui-sfml/imgui-SFML.cpp:303:57: error: no member named 'Arrow' in 'sf::Cursor'
    loadMouseCursor(ImGuiMouseCursor_Arrow, sf::Cursor::Arrow);
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/loicpottier/Documents/GitHub/projet_recherche/libs/imgui-sfml/imgui-SFML.cpp:304:61: error: no member named 'Text' in 'sf::Cursor'
    loadMouseCursor(ImGuiMouseCursor_TextInput, sf::Cursor::Text);
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/loicpottier/Documents/GitHub/projet_recherche/libs/imgui-sfml/imgui-SFML.cpp:305:61: error: no member named 'SizeAll' in 'sf::Cursor'
    loadMouseCursor(ImGuiMouseCursor_ResizeAll, sf::Cursor::SizeAll);
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

If anyone see a problem in my cmake setup, please explain me, i tried many things and i can't figure why it isn't working.

Thanks in advance !

Adding sfml sources as executable in `add_executable()` doesn't solve this.
adding sources in `target_sources` doesn't change anything either

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is facing the same issue or something similar, I just found the solution !

It was very simple in fact. When switching from fetch to submodules, I switched from official release to the last commit too..

This led to differences between SFML and imgui-SFML.

Just doing a git checkout inside of the submodules with the release version's SHA1 resolved the problem.